# Error installing two PHP Versions Ubuntu 12.04 with Plesk 11.5

Tags: 12.04, server, php

I'm trying to install a additional PHP Version (5.5.10) on a Root Server running Ubuntu 12.04 but I keep running into errors during configure. It keeps giving me the following error:

error: Cannot find imap library (libc-client.a). Please check your c-client installation.

Here is my PHP configuration script:

```
./configure '--with-libdir=lib64' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--prefix=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi/etc' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-fastcgi' '--with-bz2' '--with-curl' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi' '--with-openssl' '--with-pspell' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos' '--with-unixODBC=/usr' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite3' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli' '--with-snmp' '--enable-soap' '--with-xsl' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--enable-pdo' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-pear=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi/pear' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-intl' '--without-pdo-sqlite' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php-5.5.10-cgi/php.d'
```

I also installed this:

```
apt-get install libc-client-dev build-essential libxml2-dev libpcre3-dev libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libdb4.8-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libxpm-dev libfreetype6-dev libmysqlclient-dev postgresql-server-dev-9.1 libt1-dev libgd2-xpm-dev libgmp-dev libsasl2-dev libmhash-dev unixodbc-dev freetds-dev libpspell-dev libsnmp-dev libtidy-dev libxslt1-dev libmcrypt-dev
```

Appreciate any assistance. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the php 5.5.10 Version i downloaded from php.net was currupt. A new download and new install solved my problem.